# How to avoid using php://input?

Tags: json, http-request

I have a POST endpoint that receives a JSON payload.

I'm using the `Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http` class to try and retrieve my POST data.

If I run `$data = $this->request->getPost();`, then `$data` will be empty.

However if I run `$data = file_get_contents('php://input');` I am able to view my JSON payload as a string.

Is there a way to grab this natively through Magento?

FWIW I'm testing this through a **rest/V1 endpoint** through Postman.
This is a POST request with a chunk of (valid) JSON data in the raw data type.

Comment: try `$this->request->getContent();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `$this->request` is an instance of `Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http`, you can use the code below to get the JSON post body.

```
$json = $this->request->getContent();
$data = json_decode($json);
```